# iterate dynamically over sub lists and store its values

Tags: python, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Is there a way to store the results without having to write every sublist name?
the numbers in every array are just examples of what I want to do.
Thank you in advance.

```
        _store = []

        _arr4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        _arr3 = [1, 2, 3, _arr4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        _arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, _arr3, 8, 9]
        _arr = [1, 2, 3, _arr2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

        for _value in _arr:

            #If value is a list get it, go over that list and so on
            if isinstance( _value, list ):

                _store.append(_value)
                _sub_list = _value

                if isinstance( _sub_list, list ):

                    _store.append( _sub_list)
                    _sub_sub_list = _sub_list

                    if isinstance( _sub_sub_list, list ):

                        _store.append( _sub_list)
                        _sub_sub_sub_list = _sub_list

                        #and so on...

        print _store
```

Comment: "I want to store the results" <- the results of what? What do you want to do with them later? What does "without having to write every sublist name" mean?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, this weird convolution probably means you are not taking a healthy approach...

Comment: If you're not using the first level `_sub_list`, you can just keep using this same name and overwriting with the newly found values. But I think the recursive approach given in an answer is best.

Comment: Do you want me to copy paste all bunch of data from my database? or do you want me to expose data from my company, I think simplier questions are better then having to explain every time what I want to do, despite it really becomes clear for educative purposes.

Comment: Desired demo output in store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using recursion:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,a,5]
c = [6,b,7]

def add_to(input, output):
    for x in input:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            add_to(x, output)
        else:
            output.append(x)

result = []

add_to(c, result) # now result = [6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

The un-pythonicness of passing the output ref through the recursion can be eliminated by using a generator:

```
def flatten(input):
    for x in input:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x

result = list(flatten(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just serialize the list to JSON?

```
import json
json.dumps(arr)
```

Comment: How do you suggest OP will iterate over the values once they're serialized as one big string?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using recursion:

```
arr4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr3 = [1, 2, 3, arr4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, arr3, 8, 9]
arr = [1, 2, 3, arr2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def get_store(array):
    store = []
    for item in array:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            store.extend(get_store(item))
        else:
            store.append(item)
    return store

print get_store(arr)
```

...which outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Basically, whenever you notice that you're taking some operation and continuously nesting or repeating it, but have difficulty turning it into a for-loop, it's a good sign that you could try recursion.